# Android Ice Cream Sandwich Performance on HTC Vision / Desire Z

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, performance, htc-desire-z

I've got a HTC Vision / Desire Z (aka. T-Mobile G2), and I flashed a custom Android Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) 4.0 ROM on it. Unfortunately, performance leaves a lot to be desired.

I've tried the following so far:

- Overclocking to 1.8Ghz (device locked up, so I reverted to the safer 1.4Ghz)
- Limiting background processes to 2 (under Developer Options)

I'm wondering what the impact of enabling "*Don't keep activities: Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it*" is. Would that be a good thing, or would it hurt performance? Are there any other options I should consider for optimizing ICS performance on the G2?

Comment: It's not a good idea to have an aggressive auto-killer, as it means much more CPU work, because Activites always need to be recreated.
Which custom ROM did you flash? Do other users have the performance issues?

Comment: As I recall, it was this ROM: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1492461

I was thinking that what you said might be the case -- activities would have to be recreated. I don't know if I'm running into my upper RAM limit though, which would be a performance problem in and of itself.

I'm not sure if other users have the same performance problems that I do. It's a fairly old, single-core device, so I'm just not sure if it's just going to run like crap in general. Figured I would ask.

Comment: Did you check if the RAM is filled and how it's filled with some Android app or by using top / htop, whichever is available in a shell?

Comment: Negative -- I was unaware of those commands in the terminal emulator. I'll try those.